# I am trying to click on an option in the dropdown with the help of the li tag but not getting the output neither am i getting any error

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

```
public class CssSelector3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

        driver.get("http://qa.letslearnindia.com");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();

        driver.findElement(By.linkText("Sign in")).click();
        Thread.sleep(5000);


        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[id='inputSuccess2']")).sendKeys("tester42@gmail.com");

        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[id='inputSuccess3']")).sendKeys("123456");

        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[id='btn_login']")).click();
        Thread.sleep(5000);

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='navbar']/ul/li[2]/a")).click();

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='horizontalTab']/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/a/input")).click();
        Thread.sleep(5000);

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='full_height_base']/div/div[3]/div[3]/div[2]/div/ul[2]/li[1]/a")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='courseTitle']")).sendKeys("Automation Test");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='courseSubtitle']")).sendKeys("Automating the test cases");
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        WebElement dropdown = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='validate-me-plz']/div[1]/div[2]/div/p/span"));
        List<WebElement> li = dropdown.findElements(By.tagName("li"));
        System.out.println(li.size());
        String element;
        for(int i =0; i<li.size();i++){
            element = li.get(i).getAttribute("data-val");
            if(element.equals("English")){
                li.get(i). click();
```

Comment: Please provide the HTML of the dropdown.

Comment: <select id="courseLanguage" name="courseLanguage" class="SlectBox form-control" style="display: none;">
                                       <option value="">Select a Language</option>
<option value="English">English</option>
<option value="Hindi">Hindi</option>
<option value="Marathi">Marathi</option>
<option value="Spanish">Spanish</option>
<option value="Tamil">Tamil</option>
 <option value="Urdu">Urdu</option>
</select>

Comment: I want to click on "English"

Answer (score 0):

When choosing from `<select>` tag you should use [Select class](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/Select.html)

```
WebElement dropdown = driver.findElement(By.id("courseLanguage")); // locate the dropdown
Select select = new Select(dropdown); // initialize select
select.selectByVisibleText("English"); // choose the option with "English" as text
// select.selectByValue("English"); // choose the option with "English" as value
```

> Its still giving an error as "Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with"

To make sure the element is visible before interaction use explicit wait

```
// this will wait up to 10 seconds for the dropdown to be visible and will return the dropdown element
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
WebElement dropdown = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("courseLanguage")));

Select select = new Select(dropdown);
select.selectByVisibleText("English");
```

Comment: Its still giving an error as "Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with"

Comment: WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
  WebElement dropdown = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("courseLanguage")));
  Select select = new Select(dropdown);
     select.selectByVisibleText("English");

Comment: Hi..I used the above code but still the element does not get selected, it gives an error as "Timed out after 20 seconds waiting for visibility of element located by By.id: courseLanguage"

Comment: Please help me with the above

Answer (score 0):

try by selecting all the elements with a select tag by using findElements method
and then pass the desired element to the Select class as below :

```
   List<WebElement> AllselectTags= driver.findElements(By.tagName("select"));   
     WebElement selectedElement = AllselectTags.get(0);
        Select s = new Select(selectedElement);
        s.selectByValue("English");
```